# Encapsulate JavaFX properties in NetBeans 8?

Tags: java, netbeans, properties, javafx, encapsulation

this is my first question on StackOverflow, so I hope this is not a dumb one :-)

Is there a way to automaticaly encapsulate JavaFX properties in NetBeans 8 ?

Let's say we want to encapsulate this field :

`private SimpleIntegerProperty id;`

When I goes to Refactor > Encapsulate Fields, I obtain these lines :

```
public SimpleIntegerProperty getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public setId(SimpleIntegerProperty id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

But I'd like to get that :

```
public Integer getId() {
    return id.get();
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id.set(id);
}

public SimpleIntegerProperty idProperty() {
    return id;
}
```

Is there a simple way to do it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of refactoring, you just can go to Source->Insert Code and select *Add JavaFX Property*.
Then, on the dialog, give a name to your property, i.e. `id`, give a default value if necessary, select the type of property, i.e. `IntegerProperty`, and click OK.

Then this is what you get:

```
private final IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

public int getId() {
    return id.get();
}

public void setId(int value) {
    id.set(value);
}

public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
    return id;
}
```

Finally, you can manually change simple type `int` to `Integer`, if you need to.

Comment: How come i don't have "Add JavaFX Property" option in the context menu?